# You just need to reinterpret

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I sit, usually silently, at a very certain place
When I'm not silent, I buzz erratically, all over the place
Forgive me for my horrid rhyme, but you've seen me all the time
I'm willing to bet that you're looking at me right now

*I've overtaken every other thing that draws your attention to it,

you may think I watch over you, but you just need to reinterpret*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to say

> A monitor/screen

but saw Strawberry answered the same here is my explanation

I sit, usually silently, at a very certain place
When I'm not silent, I buzz erratically, all over the place

> A desktop monitor normally sits at one place

Forgive me for my horrid rhyme, but you've seen me all the time
I'm willing to bet that you're looking at me right now

> Looking at my monitor right now

I've overtaken every other thing that draws your attention to it,

> Our phones are now ALL Screen

you may think I watch over you, but you just need to reinterpret

> Another use of the word Monitor is someone who watches over (like a hall monitor).

Answer (score 12):

You are a

> phone

I sit, usually silently, at a very certain place

> Sits silently in one's pocket when not ringing

When I'm not silent, I buzz erratically, all over the place

> It rings and vibrates buzzing all around

Forgive me for my horrid rhyme, but you've seen me all the time

> We keep checking our phones all the time

I'm willing to bet that you're looking at me right now

> Self-explanatory

I've overtaken every other thing that draws your attention to it

> Phone is the thing that we give most of our attention to these days, even more than our food, or sleep (sad but true!)

you may think I watch over you, but you just need to reinterpret

> If reports are to be believed, government uses our phones to spy (watch) on the citizens. But, if reinterpreted, we watch our phones all the time.

Comment: Your answer is related to the correct one, but good try! +1

Comment: @SahibPrime Maybe you could add a hint as to *how* they are related?

Answer (score 6):

You are

> a clock / time?

I sit, usually silently, at a very certain place

> clocks, usually, don't make any sounds (places in public like trainstations where there are clocks with fixed positions)

When I'm not silent, I buzz erratically, all over the place

> clocktowers all over the country "buzz" at the same time (e.g. full hours) or maybe alerts on phones when people wake up buzz all over the place

Forgive me for my horrid rhyme, but you've seen me all the time

> clocks everywhere.. phone, computer, on your arm, outside...

I'm willing to bet that you're looking at me right now

> computer clock on your taskbar

I've overtaken every other thing that draws your attention to it,

> not sure about that one

you may think I watch over you, but you just need to reinterpret

> time seems to rule your day but it should be you deciding what to do when and not time (I guess?)

Comment: For line three, I definitely picture a cartoon ringing alarm clock bouncing all over the desk

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A computer?

Reasoning:

"I sit, usually silently, at a very certain place"

> Computers are generally silent and located at one place in your house due to cables etc. (Not a laptop).

"When I'm not silent, I buzz erratically, all over the place"

> When in use, the fan can often make a buzzing noise. Plus the noise from typing?

"Forgive me for my horrid rhyme, but you've seen me all the time"

> Most people 'see' their computer daily.

"I'm willing to bet that you're looking at me right now"

> I am, obviously.

"I've overtaken every other thing that draws your attention to it,"

> Computers have pretty much taken over a great deal of our lives, more so than any other appliance.

"you may think I watch over you, but you just need to reinterpret"

> We often think that computers are starting to take over our lives, but really they just facilitate that which we would have done anyway.

Comment: Welcome To Puzzling E404! Exactly what I was thinking as I read the riddle. I added spoilers to your post so other users can choose to try their hand without seeing your answer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks, tried putting in the spoilers myself, but obviously did it wrong. Have now read how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> monitor

But really only because I watch over you

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I need explanation to accept it.